# Upset plot in python for orthogroups gene count table

Tags: python, plot

I want to make an **Upset plot** from a gene count table. The categories will be species and the category members will be the groups they involve. Although I found several [examples](http://genomespot.blogspot.com/2017/09/upset-plots-as-replacement-to-venn.html) with R, there is none for Python.

What I have is a data frame that shows how many genes are found in the group for each species (this is the direct output format from Orthofinder):

```
d= {"groups":["group1", "group2", "group3"],"sp1":[1912,804, 780], "sp2":[0,0,0], "sp3": [1,0,0], "total":[1913,804,780]}
pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

What I need is to convert the data into an Upset compatible format e.g. ****group_memberships** dictionary**. I implemented the code below from the [Upset doc](https://upsetplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formats.html#Use-DataFrame-as-input:):

```
from upsetplot import from_memberships
group_memberships = {
    "group1": "sp1,sp3",
    "group2": "sp1",
    "group3": "sp1"}

#Turn this into a list of lists:
group_memberships_lists = [categories.split(",") for categories in group_memberships_lists.values()]

groups = from_memberships(group_memberships_lists)
groups
```

I've written this script that returns a dictionary for each group with the gene counts for each species.

```
def upset(df):
        counts={}
        gb = df.groupby("groups")
        sp_list=["sp1", "sp2", "sp3"]
        for group in df.loc[:,"groups"]:
            for sp in sp_list:
                list = gb[sp].get_group(group).to_list()
                for i in list:
                    if i != 0:
                        counts.setdefault(group, []).extend(list)
        return counts
    upset(df)
```

output:

```
{'group1': [1912, 1], 'group2': [804], 'group3': [780]}
```

The problem with this script is that I want the species itself not its association with the gene count however, I don't know how to shift the shape of the table to get there.

On the other hand, I also want to add the total gene count (group size) to the plot.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem! If anyone is interested in making an upset plot from Orthofinder gene count table here is my script:

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
d= {"groups":["group1", "group2", "group3"],"sp1":[1912,804, 780], "sp2":[0,0,0], "sp3": [1,0,0], "total":[1913,804,780]}
d=pd.DataFrame(data=d).set_index("groups")


group_dict={}

for index,row  in d.iterrows():
    for sp,count in row.iteritems():
        if sp != "total" and count != 0:
            group_dict.setdefault(index, []).append(sp)
group_dict
```

Then convert the **group_dict** into an upset compatible format:

```
from upsetplot import UpSet
from upsetplot import from_memberships

        
x=from_memberships(group_dict.values()).sort_values(ascending= False)
upsetplot.plot(x, subset_size='count', show_counts=True)
```

[image]